# swift func prototype confusion

Tags: swift

I was given a function stub as follows:

```
public class UserStore {
    public func login(email:String, password:String, completion:(success:Bool, error:NSError)) {

    }

    public func forgotPassword(email:String, completion:(success:Bool, error:NSError)) {

    }

    public func register(user:User, completion:(success:Bool, error:NSError)) {

    }
}
```

and I'm a bit confused -- how am I to call this?  I have tried this:

```
var error : NSError?
var success : Bool = false
UserStore.login("bob", "password", (success, error!))
```

and the compiler tells me:  extra arg in call

and this:

```
UserStore.login("bob", "password", completion:(success, error!))
```

yields: extra arg in call

and this:

```
UserStore.login("bob", "password", completion:(&success, &error))
```

which yields: extra arg in call
and this:

```
   let email = emailTextField.text
   let pw    = passwordTextField.text
   var error : NSError?
   var success : Bool = false
   var completion = (success, error )
   UserStore.login(email, pw, &completion)
```

which yields: extra arg in call.

I am running out of permutations and patience -- can anyone please shed light on how to call it?  and while you're at it, how do I edit the stubs to return success and failure (with error codes)?

Thanks!

:bp:

Comment: function(user="bob"..)?

Comment: Try making the modifier class func instead of public func

Comment: Neither was successful... but thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is  because you are calling the functions as if they are class method.

You need to create a `UserStore` instance e.g.

```
var us = UserStore()
us.login("bob", password:"password", completion:(success, error!))
```